# Using `apply` on datetime64 series in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, strftime

I have a Series of `datetime64[ns]` objects. I would like to apply `strftime('%d-%m-%Y')` to all of them, for reversing the order of year,day,month. I tried using:

```
series.apply(time.strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))
```

But I get the error:

> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Any idea on the right way to do this elegantly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
series.dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
```

Or if is necessary convert `Series` [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) first:

```
pd.to_datetime(series).dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
```